# Ionic 2 change status bar color on tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Trying to change the color of the status bar in tabs pages. It changes only the first time and after I click between tabs it doesnt change the color anymore but just keeps last tab I clicked color.

Tried with   `ionViewDidLoad()` and  also `ngOnInit()` but for tabs it seems that the statusBar function doesnt get called, how to trigger color change everytime user switches between tabs?

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#f2d602');

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using ionViewWillEnter() this function will be initiated every time when you enter that view. For more information please refer the ionic life cycle in the following link.

https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake use ionViewWillEnter method instead of ionViewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

call this function in constructor() of app.component file. It will get applied all the pages in your app

```
constructor(){
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#f2d602');
}
}
```